# How to change border in Ngb-Datepicker navigation arrows

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

[image]

Hi, I want to eliminate the blue border that is displayed after clicking the button, I have already try to target it with

```
::ng-deep{
  .ngb-dp-arrow > button:active {
   border: none !important;
}
```

But nothing seems to work, I already change the color of chevron with that approach so I'm placing my css in the correct place (component itself)

Link to reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-er2bdu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following CSS to remove the borders:

```
::ng-deep .ngb-dp-arrow-btn:focus {
  outline: 0 !important; // remove the darker blue border
  box-shadow: none !important; // remove the light blue border
}
```

There are 2 borders that appear with the `:focus` pseudo selector:

- a darker blue border - can be removed by setting `outline` to `0`
- a light blue box border - can be removed by setting `box-shadow` to `none`

Please see [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-er2bdu-82u7qz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.scss) for a working demo.

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly, could I know where you looked for the right class ? given its not in the official documentation

Comment: I inspected the DOM using Chrome's developer tools and selected the `:focus` psuedo selector so I could see what styles were applied to the element when it had focus